# Configure services with env vars at compile time

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, phpdotenv

Until now, I've been using container parameters from an unversioned `parameters.yml` file to configure some bundles. The parameters where read during the container compilation to determine which services needed to be injected in a service definition.

Today, I'd like to replace the `parameters.yml` configuration with environment variables, but as they are resolved at runtime, their value is not available when building the container, and the services have to be public afterwards.

Am I missing something here? Is there a clean way to configure services that way?

**[edit]**

I want to inject a *user provider* service into `MyService` depending on whether a `mock` feature is enabled, and provide a username.

```
# bundle configuration
my_extension:
    mock:
        enabled:  '%env(MOCK_ENABLED)%'
        provider: '%env(MOCK_PROVIDER)%'
        username: '%env(MOCK_USERNAME)%'
```

```php
<?php

class MyExtension extends Extension
{
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $configuration = new Configuration();
        $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

        // here, mock_enabled is an env var placeholder, not a boolean value
        // the condition will thus always resolve to true.
        if ($config['mock_enabled']) {

            // The other two env vars will be evaluated at runtime
            // and I'm ok with that
            $username = $config['mock_username'];
            $provider = new Definition(
                $config['mock_provider'],
                [$config['mock_username']]
            );
        } else {
            $provider = new Reference(InMemoryUserProvider::class, [[]];
        }

        $definition = new Definition(MyService::class);
        $definition->addMethodCall('setProvider', new Reference($provider));
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give a more concrete example of a use case that you need to solve?